# Mongoose how to insert an object inside an object that is inside an array

Tags: mongoose

I want to push an object inside an object that is inside an array. To make it clearer, here is the structure of what my mongoose model is like this:

```
username: {
        type: String,
        min: 1,
        required:true,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    folders:[
        {
            title:String, 
            files:[{
                fileID: String,  
                type: String
            }]
        }
    ]
```

each folder would automatically get an object id. What I want to do is to add an object to the specific folder's files. The files is an array which is where I would push the object. I tried adding it using something like this:

```
await User.findOne({username:username}, {$push: 
                    {[folderID.files]: [ {title:'title',  type:'type'} ]}
                })
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the folder that need update by id then use [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#mongodb-update-up.-) operator to push your new file to files array of that folder:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { username: username, "folders._id": folderID }, 
  { $push: { "folders.$.files": {title:'title',  type:'type'} }}
)
```

Comment: oh wait sorry I meant to use findOneAndUpdate. will this work without using findOneAndUpdate?

Comment: Oh I forgot it. You need to use findOneAndUpdate.

Comment: Hey thank you! it worked perfectly! Do you think you can send me a link to where you found out about this? I tried really hard looking for this in the mongoose documentary

Comment: You can find how to use mongodb operators here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/